# GROUP BY multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm trying to draw stats out of a table and depending on the increment, group them by year, month, date.

The table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE `channel_stats` (
  `channel_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `datestamp` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `udatestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip_country` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `billing_country` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_method` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_status` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_currency` char(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_amount` decimal(13,4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_amount` decimal(13,4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `trans_fees` decimal(13,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `volume` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `channel_stats_UNIQUE` (`channel_id`,`datestamp`,`ip_country`,`billing_country`,`payment_method`,`trans_type`,`trans_status`,`trans_currency`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and the query I'm trying to use (which doesnt work) looks something like this

```
select 
    datestamp,
    trans_type,
    trans_status,
    sum(base_amount) 'total_amount',
    sum(trans_fees) 'total_fees',
    sum(volume) 'total_volume'
from channel_stats
where channel_id = p_channel_id
and udatestamp >= p_startdate and udatestamp <= p_enddate
group by case 
    when p_increment = 'days' then
        (datestamp)
    when p_increment = 'months' then
        (year(datestamp), month(datestamp))
    when p_increment = 'years' then
        (year(datestamp))
end, trans_type, trans_status;
```

does anyone know how i can achieve this?

EDIT:

How it would get called for each increment

```
call uic_get_dashboard_transactions_100('1',(unix_timestamp() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 30),unix_timestamp(),'days');
call uic_get_dashboard_transactions_100('1',(unix_timestamp() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 365),unix_timestamp(),'months');
call uic_get_dashboard_transactions_100('1',(unix_timestamp() - 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 5),unix_timestamp(),'years');
```

It works if I break it out which I think in terms of processing, is a better way of doing it, just creates more code than probably necessary. Current solution:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `uic_get_stats_transactions_100`(
    p_channel_id int unsigned,
    p_startdate int unsigned,
    p_enddate int unsigned,
    p_increment varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
    case p_increment
        when 'days' then
            select 
                datestamp,
                trans_type,
                trans_status,
                sum(base_amount) 'total_amount',
                sum(trans_fees) 'total_fees',
                sum(volume) 'total_volume'
            from channel_stats
            where channel_id = p_channel_id
            and udatestamp >= p_startdate and udatestamp <= p_enddate
            group by datestamp, trans_type, trans_status;
        when 'months' then
            select 
                datestamp,
                trans_type,
                trans_status,
                sum(base_amount) 'total_amount',
                sum(trans_fees) 'total_fees',
                sum(volume) 'total_volume'
            from channel_stats
            where channel_id = p_channel_id
            and udatestamp >= p_startdate and udatestamp <= p_enddate
            group by year(datestamp), month(datestamp), trans_type, trans_status;
        when 'years' then
            select 
                datestamp,
                trans_type,
                trans_status,
                sum(base_amount) 'total_amount',
                sum(trans_fees) 'total_fees',
                sum(volume) 'total_volume'
            from channel_stats
            where channel_id = p_channel_id
            and udatestamp >= p_startdate and udatestamp <= p_enddate
            group by year(datestamp), trans_type, trans_status;
    end case;
END
```

Comment: It would be even easier for us if you could include some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: That GROUP BY wont work but you can build different SUMs moving the CASEs inside `sum(CASE WHEN p_increment = 'days' THEN base_amount END ) as Total Amount Days` and so on

Comment: Interesting idea @Mihai. Not sure how that would work though

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to take advantage of the 'string' format of dates:
`LEFT(datestamp, 4)` is the same as `YEAR(datestamp)`, etc:

```
mysql> SELECT LEFT(NOW(), 4), LEFT(NOW(), 7), LEFT(NOW(), 10);
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| LEFT(NOW(), 4) | LEFT(NOW(), 7) | LEFT(NOW(), 10) |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
| 2015           | 2015-02        | 2015-02-15      |
+----------------+----------------+-----------------+
```

So, your complex `CASE` boils down to deciding between 4, 7, and 10, thereby shortening the code significantly.  (This trick works for DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP, but not timestamps stored as INT.)

As a side note: It would be better to use `country CHAR(2) CHARSET ascii`, which takes only 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I hate having a CASE in the middle ofSQL. It looks and feels clumsy.

You should think of this in terms of Dynamic SQL.

Perhaps something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `uic_get_stats_transactions_100`(
    p_channel_id int unsigned,
    p_startdate int unsigned,
    p_enddate int unsigned,
    p_increment varchar(10)
)
BEGIN
    SET @p_inc = p_increment;
    SET @p_inclist = 'days,months,years';
    SET @ndx = FIND_IN_SET(@p_inc,@p_inclist);
    SET @groupby =
        IF(
            @ndx=0,'datestamp',
            ELT(
                @ndx,
                'datestamp',
                'DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,''%Y-%m-01'')',
                'DATE_FORMAT(datestamp,''%Y'')'
            )
        );
    SET @sql = 'select datestamp,trans_type,trans_status,';
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'sum(base_amount) ''total_amount'',');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'sum(trans_fees) ''total_fees'',');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'sum(volume) ''total_volume'' ');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'from channel_stats where ');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'channel_id = p_channel_id and ');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'udatestamp >= p_startdate and ');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'udatestamp <= p_enddate ');
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,'group by ',@groupby);
    SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,',trans_type, trans_status');
    PREPARE s FROM @sql; EXECUTE s; DEALLOCATE PREPARE s;
END
```

If `p_increment` is not `days`, `months`, or `years`, the default is `days`